# Dynamically change $primary variable in angular material theme?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, scss-mixins

Here is the case
I am getting color from DB and need to set primary color into my angular website.
I need to update following value in file `src/assets/sass/components/_variables.demo.scss`

```
$primary:                                           #CC2128; // Bootstrap variable
$primary-hover:                                     #008cb7; // Custom variable
$primary-light:                                     #E1F0FF; // Custom variable
$primary-inverse:                                   #FFFFFF; // Custom variable
```

I tried

```
:root{
--primary-color: #fffff
}

$primary: var(--primary-color);
```

and changing --primary-color from my app component like

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', color-from-db);
```

I am getting error that `var(--primary-color); is not a color`

however this method is working fine for all custom styles under `src/styles.scss` path.

How can I do this if I am doing it wrong?